# Why doesn't knitr allow directional assignment?

Tags: r, knitr

R allows directional assignments, knitr reverses the direction and responds the error. Here is the code:

```
    \documentclass[letter]{article}
    \title{y}
    \author{z}
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    <<assignment, echo = TRUE>>=
        (X <- 10)
        (10 -> Y)
    @
    \end{document}

`    (X <- 10)
    ## [1] 10
    (10 <- Y)
    ## Error:
     invalid (do set) left-hand side to assignment`
```

Comment: Fair question, but why would you want to use a rightward assignment?

Comment: have you tried tidy=FALSE?

Comment: 1. please run `update.packages()` and update R as well if possible; this problem has been fixed; 2. in the next version of knitr (1.6), tidy=FALSE will be the default, so the problem will go away